# Rewrite query into path using htaccess

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

How can I make `htaccess` rewrite the following URL structure:

```
http://example.com/detail.php?id=polo&categ=wears
```

to

```
http://example.com/wears/polo/
```

I have tried the below code but it didn't work for me.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(admin|css|fonts|ico|include|js|images|img|products|slide)/(.*)$ $2/$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ detail.php?id=$1&categ=$2
</IfModule>
```

Comment: "rewrite the following URL structure" - note that your code is trying to do the complete opposite (which is good). It wouldn't make sense to rewrite the URL to `/wears/polo/` (this would probably result in a 404).

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me when I include the trailing slash in the URL.

working -> `http://example.com/wears/polo/`

not working -> `http://example.com/wears/polo`

Also, you need to exclude the slash character from the `.*` expression.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(admin|css|fonts|ico|include|js|images|img|products|slide)/(.*)$ $2/$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ detail.php?id=$1&categ=$2
</IfModule>
```

Comment: "Your code works for me" - Except that the values are reversed. You need to switch the order of the backreferences `$1` and `$2`.

Answer (score 0):

***Try this***

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(\w+)/(\w+)$ detail.php?categ=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: In per-directory context (`.htaccess` file) you need to remove the slash prefix from the `RewriteRule` _pattern_. (You also missing a slash at the end of the URL that is present in the example.)